# Hibernate NPE when using function() to call native sql method within jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception, spring-data

I've got the following query which is used within a spring-data repository and runs fine in the jpa console. It has a subselect query which uses jpa's function() to call a native MySQL database method:

```sql
select run1.someAttribute1 AS someAttribute1, 
       run1.someAttribute2 AS someAttribute2, 
       run1.someAttribute3 AS someAttribute3, 
(select
    sum(function('timestampdiff', SECOND, run2.runStartTime, run2.runEndTime)) 
    from runTable AS run2 
    where run2.anotherAttribute1 = run1.anotherAttribute1 
    and run2.anotherAttribute2 = run1.someAttribute2 
    and run2.anotherAttribute3 = run1.someAttribute3
) AS runtime, 
sum(
    case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1   
    else 0 end
) AS numberOfSomething1,
sum(
    case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1     
    else 0 end
) AS numberOfSomething2, 
sum(
    case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 
    else 0 end
) AS numberOfSomething3, 
sum(
    case when type(event) = SomeEvent and event.someType = '...' then 1 
    else 0 end
) AS numberOfSomething4, 
sum(
    case when type(event) = SomeEvent2 then 1 
    else 0 end
) AS numberOfSomething5 from runTable AS run1 left join run1.events AS event 
group by someAttribute1, someAttribute2, someAttribute3 
order by 
    max(function('right', function('left', someAttribute1, 8), 3)) desc,    
    someAttribute2 desc, 
    someAttribute3 desc
```

The method timestampdiff is registered in my custom MySQLDialect:

```
public class MySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect {

    public MySQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("timestampdiff", new SQLFunctionTemplate(LongType.INSTANCE, "timestampdiff(?1, ?2, ?3)"));
    }
}
```

A spring boot application uses this repository and starts up without any error. When opening the page which is linked to the repository (through a bean and service layer of course), it loads up and shows the desired result in a datatable.

The problem occurs when I implement any unit (integration) test (i guess through scanning the repository package?!). While the unit test is starting up, Hibernate throws a NullPointerException.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/application-context-test.xml"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("de. ... .persistence.repositories")
public class AnalysisServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private AnalysisService analysisService;

    @Inject
    private CarService carService;

    @Test
    public void saveAnalysis() {

        ...
    }  

}
```

Application-context-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!-- Base package for repositories, services and daos-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="de. ... .analysis"/>

</beans>
```

Stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '...Service' defined in file [C:\_Projekte\...\...Service.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '...Repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de. ... .Repository.getSomething()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '...Repository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de. ... .repositories....Repository.getSomething()!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List de. ... .repositories....Repository.getSomething()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1011)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:779)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2466)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.aliasedSelectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2509)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2239)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 66 more
```

So i debugged into that problem and as you can see in the stacktrace, Hibernate fails during AST building within the method `findFunctionReturnType(String functionName, SQLFunction sqlFunction, AST firstArgument)` which is located in the `SessionFactoryHelper` class. That method tries to resolve the argumentType through casting firstArgument to an SqlNode and calling `getDataType()` on it and finally it returns sqlFunction.getReturnType with that argumentType.

In my case, the NPE occurs when resolving the argumentType from the subselect's sum function. functionName is "sum", sqlFunction is an instance of SumFunction and firstArgument is "function(timestampdiff)" (instance of MethodeNode). When `getReturnType(argumentType, ... )` is called on return, argumentType is null because obvoiusly, it cannot be resolved from "function(timestampdiff)", thus causing the NPE.

**Question**

Is there any way i can use function() together with hibernate in a subselect? Why does it fail in my unit tests while working perfectly in the spring boot application?

**EDIT**
It appears to only work for me in my spring boot application. One of m coworkers has it also fail for the application startup. There is nothing different from our code and IDE

I've already read about that magic NPE but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Please add application-context-test.xml and application-context.xml (if available)

Comment: Added. They are both the same.

Comment: Then , most probably you are configuring something more while invoking the Spring Boot App(Or Spring auto-configure it for you) , else as noted in the answer by @Jens Schauder , maybe there is a dependency mixture in your classpath, which during Spring Boot its gets resolved properly , but when invoking the JUnit runner it is picking up the wrong libs

Comment: if you run IDEA it has a lot of cache which you have to clean. This can cause your already not working project to pass in some cases. Tests have their own build. Try to rebuild project, update maven dependencies in idea, after that clean-install the project. That should update. If test and spring-boot are still different, it might be that some annotations are not read properly during test phase and thus you're left without some piece of data.

Comment: Was your Problem solved with the new answer or any other? If, please post the solving answer or accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a dependency/class loading issue. I'd try the following

- make a diff of your dependencies/classpath. If you're using maven use its dependency plugin to print the dependency tree (`mvn dependency:tree`). Look out for duplicate dependencies and different versions in test and production code. Print out the classpath at runtime and again compare it between test and production.
- put a breakpoint in the `MySqlDialect` to ensure it gets loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry for that late answer but that was indeed the problem. We had several files which defined the dialect for each module (tests etc.) and there it was picking up an old dialect.
My coworker is using eclipse and it uses a different application path and therefore a different config file for the dialect. That was why it was working for me while it failed for him.